# Алгоритм поиска пересечения двух ломаных линий

Tags: алгоритм, геометрия

Есть два массива точек, которые образуют две ломаные линии. Существует ли алгоритм поиска точек пересечения этих двух линий?

На ум пока приходит поиск пересечений каждого из отрезков обоих линий.

Comment: Ух, кривых...можно, например, если эти кривые соответствуют некоторым графикам функций( притом совсем не обязательно одинаковых ).

Comment: @0xFFh ни как не соответсвуют графикам функции

Comment: Боюсь, тогда, если легко с помощью математики, то иначе - никак.

Comment: Массив точек не может описывать кривую, только ломаную. Случаев 2:

1) Допустим, приближение соответствует ситуации "1 точка = 1 пиксель". Тогда "кривые" пересекаются в точках с одинаковыми координатами.

2) Для приближение кривой соседние точки соединяются отрезками. Тогда перебираем пары соседних точек для "кривых", и смотрим, пересекаются ли соединяющие их отрезки.

Comment: @klopp не так выразился. Ломаная линия. А так да, думаю, только перебор всех отрезков меня спасёт.

Comment: все отрезки перебирать не нужно. Упрощаю алгоритм. Разбиваете по координате x на группы, кол-во групп нужно подобрать экспериментально. Сами группы должны немножко перекрываться (на одну точку). Теперь можно просто проверять значение по y координате в каждой группе. Очень легко проверить, когда они находятся далеко и не могут пересекаться. Такие группы сразу выбрасываются. Например, первая группа - 5,7,10. Вторая - 30,23,40. А дальше, либо перебираем все отрезки на предмет пересечения, либо, если там сглаживание, фантазируем дальше.

Answer (score 3):

Классический хрестоматийный алгоритм поиска всех  пересечений в наборе отрезков - алгоритм sweep line. Тот факт, что в вашем случае мы имеем дело не с произвольным набором отрезков, а с двумя ломаными, как мне кажется, ситуации сильно не меняет.

Другое дело, если вам заранее известна какая-то дополнительная информация о ваших ломаных.

Например, если вам заранее известно, что ваши ломаные являются *монотонными* вдоль какого-то общего направления, то в такой ситуации поиск всех пересечений можно выполнить простым линейным проходом по ломаным.

Comment: А можно дополнить ссылкой на алгоритм, или даже его схематическим описанием?